# ASHX Handler not working correctly with clients outside my network

Tags: c#, excel, external, ashx, corrupt

I have an application that is used by people inside and outside my organization.  This application exports both Excel (.xlsx) and PDF files.  I'm having trouble with the file exports.  It works fine for people that are on my network, but people outside my network are getting a "File read error.  File type is unsupported or the file is corrupted", and the file will only be 127 bytes instead of it's correct size (normally about 2 megabytes).  I need people outside my network to be able to successfully download and open the files.

I've also tried running handler classes tailored to each specific file type, I've tried opening up the directory with the file to let "Everyone" have read access, I'm really not sure on how to fix this.  The web server is running IIS 10.

```
public class fileExportHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fileToExport = "";
        string fileName = "exportedFile";
        string fileType = "";

        System.Web.HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if ((request.QueryString["fileToExport"] != null))
        {
            fileToExport = request.QueryString["fileToExport"].ToString();

            string[] fileParts = fileToExport.Split('.');
            fileType = fileParts[1];

            if ((request.QueryString["fileName"] != null))
            {
                fileName = request.QueryString["fileName"].ToString();
            }
        }

        fileToExport = @"E:\Website\Cascade\" + fileToExport;

        //send the file to the browser
        System.Web.HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        if(fileType == "pdf")
            contentType = "application/pdf";

        Response.ContentType = contentType;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + fileType);
        Response.TransmitFile(fileToExport);

        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you open the 127-byte file in a text editor, does it happen to have an error message in it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out.  It was a network issue, my network people had moved me to a new server, and people outside my organization were seeing the old server, but people inside were seeing the new version.  I got them to get the people outside my organization to see the new server, and that resolved my issue.